# hibernate to disk not restoring, but suspend to ram is working

Tags: ubuntu, debian, boot, grub, hibernate

I have Debian 6, I have also seen this under Ubuntu (can not remember how I fixed it).

I can hibernate, but when I switch on the system cold boots (it does not restore previous session).

---

***Note suspend works fine.***
Have looked in `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`
Shows for each `suspend suspend` block a `resume suspend` block, but `hibernate hibernate' is not followed by`resume hibernate` ( I assume that is what is expected.

---

Installed package hibernate, as was thinking it may be needed, but made no difference.

---

I just started looking and can't find `/usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-hibernate-linux` or `/usr/lib/hal` I searched for power files (is it all there?:

```
find /usr/lib -iname "*power*"
/usr/lib/libupower-glib.so.1
/usr/lib/klibc/bin/poweroff
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/axiom/test/test_powerup.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/axiom/test/test_powerup.py
/usr/lib/upower
/usr/lib/upower/upowerd
/usr/lib/libupower-glib.so.1.0.1
/usr/lib/gnome-power-manager
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/OpenGL/raw/GL/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.pyc
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/OpenGL/raw/GL/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/OpenGL/GL/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.pyc
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/OpenGL/GL/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/coherence/upnp/services/servers/switch_power_server.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/coherence/upnp/services/servers/switch_power_server.pyc
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/coherence/upnp/services/clients/switch_power_client.pyc
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/coherence/upnp/services/clients/test/test_switch_power_client.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/coherence/upnp/services/clients/test/test_switch_power_client.pyc
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/coherence/upnp/services/clients/switch_power_client.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/coherence/upnp/core/xml-service-descriptions/SwitchPower1.xml
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/power-manager
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/power-manager/libpower-manager.so
/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/power-manager/power-manager.rb-plugin
```

Comment: Do you have a swap partition or just a swap file? Hibernating to a swap file is supported in theory but sometimes requires some hand-holding. Swap partitions should work out of the box (at least they do on Debian 5).

Comment: it is a partition

Comment: This issue has now fixed it self, there is nothing in synaptics history to say that I installed something to fix it. It may have been an update, are these in the same history log? BUT Redetection of my 'option' modem is now slower.

Answer (score 11):

I've just had to deal with this on a laptop running Debian Testing (Jessie/Sid).

Possibly relevant: swap partition on an LVM volume (non-encrypted) at `/dev/vg1/swap`.

To make the system resume after hibernation, I had to edit `/etc/default/grub` and change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/mapper/vg1-swap"
```

and then run `update-grub`.

If you'd rather the kernel didn't check for resume images when you choose a recovery option from the GRUB menu, you'd want to modify `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` instead of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`.

I would have expected `update-grub` to write any necessary `resume=` parameters into `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` on its own, without my needing to be this explicit about it.

However, the only mention of `resume=` inside the script fragments in `/etc/grub.d` is in a piece that has something to do with OSX support. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Worked on Debian 11 Bullseye with a small change. Instead of `resume=/dev/mapper/vg1-swap`, I wrote `resume=UUID=1603aad4-2435-4da2-9520-c21b70fa9be3` where `1603aad4-2435-4da2-9520-c21b70fa9be3` is the UUID of my swap partition. To get the UUID, I ran `ls /dev/disk/by-uuid -la` and took the UUID against the `../../sda3` entry (my swap partition)

Answer (score 4):

This is a common issue for hibernate and suspend in Ubuntu / Debian.

install uswsusp

```
sudo apt-get install uswsusp
```

then try the following for suspend and hibernate respectively,

```
sudo s2ram

sudo s2disk
```

if it works, then you can make it permanent, back up the following,

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-suspend-linux /usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-suspend-linux.bak

sudo cp /usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-hibernate-linux /usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-hibernate-linux.bak
```

and edit the following,

```
/usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-suspend-linux

#!/bin/sh
/sbin/s2ram –force

/usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-hibernate-linux

#!/bin/sh
/sbin/s2disk
```

Comment: I am thinking that this is an alternative suspend/hibernate subsystem. I will try if can't fix the current one.

Comment: right, let us know the result. you need to install the proper drivers for it to work. this is just an alternative.

Comment: can't find `/usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-hibernate-linux` see question

Comment: I have discovered that the uswsusp package is missing from debian squeeze. I could get it from testing or unstable repository, but have to be careful about not pulling in other dependencies. I would like to know if it will fix it. Is uswsusp needed for hibernate. Or should pm-utils be enough. (suspend it ram is working fine.)

Comment: Amazing, working for me: sudo s2ram

Answer (score 1):

If you have change your hard disk or the partition table, then
your computer will save a session, but it won't be able to resume it upon power up, acting as if it was rebooted rather than hibernated.

In this case, you have to inform initramfs-tools about the correct partition uuid.
First of all, take note of the id of your swap partition with

`$ ls /dev/disk/by-uuid -la`

Then, edit the file /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume accordingly.

Finally update initramfs with

`# update-initramfs -u`

It it still doesn't work, try to specify the restore partition to Grub too. However, it should not be necessary.

Edit the file /etc/default/grub specifying the UUID of your swap partition:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=6098d082-4654-4840-8937-7337d14b2c5d other-option=value"`

or simply use the device

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/sda1 other-option=value"`

Don't forget to update Grub.

`# update-grub`

Reboot, and try to hibernate:

`# pm-hibernate`

Answer (score 1):

```
# update-initramfs -u
```

This was the missing piece in my similar case. When *resume from a successful hibernate started failing, after changing the swap partition*. A lot of advice suggested the grub command-line fix (like mentioned in earlier answer here).

However on my system  (Ubuntu 14.04) hibernate used to work OK, without the resume parameter in grub, before the change to the swap partition. So I realized there must be some other way the resume is handled.

The sequence to enable the hibernate/resume after changes to swap partition change (after a new UUID has been assigned to the swap partition device, per `blkid` or `ls /dev/disk/by-uuid -la`):

1. Edit `/etc/fstab` to change to the swap's new UUID
2. Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` to reflect the new swap's UUID
3. Run `update-initramfs -u` to rebuild the `/boot/initrd.img*`
4. Reboot

Thanks to @Demis Palma!

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising (I can't test now, I will the next time things go wrong).

Answer (score 0):

For suse the solution can be found here:

https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000020287

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/448731)